# No official example for navbar on UI Bootstrap?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Why isn't there an official navbar example?

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Searching on the web, I've found a few examples but they don't work on the latest released AngularUI version and Bootstrap.  All the examples I've found were for older versions.

Comment: ya! you are right, you can refer [official bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/) navbar examples to get idea

Comment: Here is an example you can use: http://plnkr.co/edit/gfYzUq4qpB3P8mkPXYZY?p=preview.  It was meant to answer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30235487/angular-ui-bootstrap-responsive-menu-closing-menu-when-clicking-off-it/30289877#30289877, so that is the purpose for the extra div.  If you have a specific question, post your non-working code so others can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one I forked and got working:

**AngularJS v1.3.15**

**angular-ui-bootstrap 0.12.1**

**Bootstrap v3.3.2**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" ng-controller="NavbarController">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" aria-expanded="true">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse in" collapse="isCollapsed" aria-expanded="true">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown" dropdown>
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
              </li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
              </li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/2KQrqtrvHSiGjWZiHMB3?p=preview